# bash variable - escaping point

Tags: bash, variables, escaping, point

Im trying to save text in variable.
But the point will translated as dir.

```
M2_1="GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO '$USER'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '$MYSQL_PASSWORD';"
```

How can i escape `*.*` ?

example output should be:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'web88'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '123456789';"
```

Comment: always quote the variable so use echo "$M2_1" instead of echo $M2_1. The latter can cause unusual behaviour

Answer (score 3):

It works for me. You are probably not quoting the variable when using it later:

```
M2_1="GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO '$USER'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '$MYSQL_PASSWORD';"
echo "$M2_1"
```

Comment: @mostworld77 always use `""` for `echo`ing strings.

Comment: @Antarus: variables rather than strings